# UiCollectionView Accessibility Focus

Tags: ios, swift, uicollectionview, accessibility

I am trying to get UICollectionView focus for accessibility before it focuses on the uicollectionview cell. Is there a way to do that so I can announce differently based on focus on view vs the cell?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You didn't indicate but I suggest you want to focus using VoiveOver so, as is *(iOS 12)*, it's [impossible to focus](https://a11y-guidelines.orange.com/mobile_EN/dev-ios.html#hide-elements) a collection view *(parent view)* and its cells  *(children)* with this accessibility feature: parent and chidren can't be accessible all together.

However, you can reach this purpose by **creating a transparent view as an  accessible element over the collection view** *(same frame)* and [specify the reading order](https://a11y-guidelines.orange.com/mobile_EN/dev-ios.html#reading-order) so as to read out this view just before the first collection view cell.

This workaround will allow you to **get UICollectionView focus for accessibility before it focuses on the UICollectionViewCell**.

Besides, further information are available at this WWDC video [detailed summary](https://a11y-guidelines.orange.com/mobile_EN/dev-ios-wwdc-18230.html#Demo) where a demo provides coding steps to perfectly show a carousel with VoiceOver if need be.